# Image and Title in Tab Bar Controller get’s overlap iPhone X?

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-x

Tab Bar Item inside Tab Bar Controller get’s overlap in iPhone X.
Any Solution for this ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Issue found to be related to animation.
- I was able to resolve this issue.
- By sub classing UITabBar from Interface builder with CustomTabBarClass

**Swift Code**
- Class CustomTabBarClass.swift

```
class CustomTabBarClass: UITabBar {

var oldSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()

    if oldSafeAreaInsets != safeAreaInsets {
        oldSafeAreaInsets = safeAreaInsets

        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        superview?.setNeedsLayout()
        superview?.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let bottomInset = safeAreaInsets.bottom
        if bottomInset > 0 && size.height < 50 && (size.height + bottomInset < 90) {
            size.height += bottomInset
        }
    }
    return size
}

override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set {
        var tmp = newValue
        if let superview = superview, tmp.maxY != 
        superview.frame.height {
            tmp.origin.y = superview.frame.height - tmp.height
        }

        super.frame = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective C Code**
- CustomTabBarClass.m

```
@implementation CustomTabBarClass{
    UIEdgeInsets oldSafeAreaInsets;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    oldSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}


- (void)safeAreaInsetsDidChange {
    [super safeAreaInsetsDidChange];

    if (!UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(oldSafeAreaInsets, self.safeAreaInsets)) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];

        if (self.superview) {
            [self.superview setNeedsLayout];
            [self.superview layoutSubviews];
        }
    }
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    size = [super sizeThatFits:size];

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        float bottomInset = self.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
        if (bottomInset > 0 && size.height < 50 && (size.height + bottomInset < 90)) {
            size.height += bottomInset;
        }
    }

    return size;
}


- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self.superview) {
        if (frame.origin.y + frame.size.height != self.superview.frame.size.height) {
            frame.origin.y = self.superview.frame.size.height - frame.size.height;
        }
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a perfect answer but below code solve my problem.

1. create a subclass for your tabbarcontroller
2. add code in **viewDidLoad** method

   let width = tabBar.bounds.width

   ```
   if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
       switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {

       case 2436:
           let tabSize = CGSize(width: width/5, height: 83)
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tabSize)
           selectionImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabSize.width, height: tabSize.height))
           selectionImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


       default:
           let tabSize = CGSize(width: width/5, height: 49)
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tabSize)
           selectionImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabSize.width, height: tabSize.height))
           selectionImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


       }
   }
   ```

Hope it may help you.!